# IOS ALAsset defaultRepresentation returns a low quality photo

Tags: ios, image, photo, alasset

I have an IOS app that retrieves photos from the device using ALAsset defaultRepresentation. The problem is that sometimes the images I receive are not the full quality images.

For example: there was an image that was 2.5MB when I emailed it. However when I called the (size) method on the default representation of the same image it was only 200KB. When I went to the photo gallery and selected the "Revert" option for the photo in edit mode, and then opened my app again and called the (size) method on the default representation of the same photo it returned the correct size 2.5MB.

This does not make any sense to me. How do I get the full image then?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question directly yet - but I can tell you how to avoid it. When a filter is enabled on the iphone (in iphone app, bottom right, tap three dots) you likely have a filter enabled like "Chrome" or "Instant" or "Transfer".

Click the "None" when taking your photos, and they will come through full resolution in your application. Apparently Apple resizes photos down considerably when applying filters.